# Dual Monitor on MacBook Pro 13 inch Touch Bar

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi

I have recently bought 2 Dell monitors (S2419H) and would like to use them as two additional screens with my 13 inch TouchBar MacBook Pro. However, when I connected both screens using an HDMI/USB C adaptor, the two monitors displayed the same thing i.e. only 2 desktop screens are being shown. I have  tried fixing this on the arrangement tab but only 2 screens are being shown there. Is there a way I can have 3 distinct screens?

Comment: *Which* MacBook Pro 13?  What version of macOS?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335928/2018-macbook-pro-dual-monitors?rq=1

Comment: MacBook Pro 13 inch with MacOS Mojave